# Any alternatives to libhand?

Tags: opengl, computer-vision, robotics, ogre, libhand

**[LibHand](http://www.libhand.org/)** seems to be tightly integrated with **OGRE** for rendering. And extending any OGRE program beyond the basics is an uphill task.

Are there any alternatives to LibHand? I'm hoping to use it with simple OpenGL programs.

Comment: As an experienced SO user, you should know that we're not a replacement for Google.

Comment: @NicolBolas Since I'm not familiar with this research area, there might be different keywords or jargon which I'm not familiar with. That affects what I can search with Google.